# Algorithm of STDEV and STDEVP in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, statistics

In my project we use STDEV function to calculate standard deviation. Can anyone point me to where the algorithms are explained used by SQL Server? I need to know it from a trusted source.

Comment: Are you looking for confirmation that the functions do what they're supposed to? If so, documentation doesn't do that; running data through will. But even that is really picking nuts. Neither of those functions is particularly tricky.

Comment: No, I believe that the function do what they are supposed to but I need to be able to describe the algorithm in a report and it seems that there are several ways to calculate stadard deviation, right? Maybe Im wrong here, is there several ways to implement the calculation but the core mathematical algorithm is the same?

Comment: I'm not a statistician, bit I'm sure there are multiple algorithms to do those calculations. However, people who *are* statisticians vet those algorithms to make sure they do the right thing. And I'd bet large sums of money that MS has implemented one of them correctly.

Comment: Im sorry but it seems you are not reading my reply properly. What Pawel Dyl is writing seems to be my solution. What Im seeking is an explanation of how SQL server calculates the standard deviation, not a proof of that the calculations is correct. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

STDEVP is Population Standard Deviation, STDEV is Sample Standard Deviation. Knowing this, take a look at this explanation: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15098/sample-standard-deviation-vs-population-standard-deviation

Comment: I have learned that there are several ways to calculate Sample Standard Deviation. I found a page that describes algorithms that calculate variance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance and this one http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2008/09/26/comparing-three-methods-of-computing-standard-deviation/. So which one is used in SQL Server?